# react-leaflet-heatmap-layer throwing error: TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, heatmap, react-leaflet

I'm trying to use the react-leaflet-heatmap-layer module to add a heatmap to my react-leaflet map. I installed it via npm, and followed all the right steps, but I can't get the component to work.

There are two errors which I've come across:
**1. Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-leaflet-heatmap-layer'.**

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-leaflet-heatmap-layer'. 'path/node_modules/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer/lib/HeatmapLayer.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-leaflet-heatmap-layer';`
```

@types isn't available for this module, so I tried to fix it by creating a global.d.ts file in the src folder, though I doubt I did it correctly because this error only seems to disappear when I have the .d.ts file open in my VSCode. Other sources suggested editing the tsconfig.json file, but I couldn't find one, and I doubt my React project is even supposed to have one.

**2. TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined**
This error shows up on the browser when I do `npm start`. According to another source online, this error arose with a different leaflet module because it wasn't compatible with the updated versions of react, however I'm not sure if this is the error with my code as well. Here are the versions of react and the modules I'm using:

```
"leaflet": "^1.7.1",
"leaflet.heat": "^0.2.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-leaflet": "^3.2.0",
"react-leaflet-heatmap-layer": "^2.0.0",
```

A lot of other sources online say that this error is most probably due to incorrectly importing the module, but I'm pretty certain I did everything the documentation told me to do.\
`import HeatmapLayer from "react-leaflet-heatmap-layer";`

Please help.

Comment: `react-leaflet` 3.0+ broke compatibility with existing `react-leaflet` plugins like `react-leaflet-heatmap-layer`. Only plugins tagged with `react-leaflet-v3` tag on nom are compatible https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords%3Areact-leaflet-v3

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for letting me know. So currently, the only way to use this plugin would be to use an older version of react-leaflet?

Comment: Yes. I also found this branch in a repo that appears to have done the conversion: https://github.com/boromisp/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer/tree/react-leaflet-3/src

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to have a working example using that branch? I couldn't figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: The package is not published publicly so you would need to clone the repo and run `yarn run build` then use `yarn link` to link the package locally to your project https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link/

Answer (score 0):

A newer *unofficial*(?) version of react-leaflet-heatmap-layer has been published that is compatible with react-leaflet 3.x and 4.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3

Note that publisher is not the original maintainer and the underlying source of this newer package is unclear.